Mailing server not receiving incoming-emails sent by addresses outside of my domain
I am using a shared hosting service (iFastNet) to host my website (https://ender.ing/). I was able to get my mailing system to work just fine when I set my DNS records to point to the shared hosting domain provided by them. (sv63.ifastnet12.org) By doing this I could send and receive emails normally.
But recently I wanted to change my MX records to point to an A record that points to the same IP Address of the shared domain (sv63.ifastnet12.org). But by doing so, I could no longer receive in-coming mail sent by addresses outside of that shared hosting service - I could still send emails to other accounts on that mailing server and receive them just fine, but I could no longer receive emails sent from outside of that shared mailing server (while still retaining the ability to send emails).
I suspect that might be because the SSL certificate of the shared server IP Address only includes "sv63.ifastnet12.org", not my domain. Is that correct, or is there something else I am missing here?
DNS setup that works (can send and receive emails)
DNS setup that doesn't work (can send emails, but can't receive emails from outside the mailing server - e.g. emails sent by exm1@ender.ing to exm2@ender.ing are received, but emails sent from exm@gmail.com to exm2@ender.ing are not received, even though Gmail successfully sent the message)

Without the actual records (which, BTW, are public already), it is not clear to me what the problem is, other than you are doing something you don't seem to understand and is different from what your provider has instructed you to do.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Paul I did try to contact my provider, but they told me that the setup I did was supposed to work.

I suspect that might be because the SSL certificate of the shared server IP Address only includes "sv63.ifastnet12.org", not my domain. - quite possible. Any mail testing service can validate this for you.


Always check your logs 2) please don't post links to images of your control panel - tell us what the DNS records are as reported by nslookup or dig.


Why do you want to change the MX record?

The problem lies in how you've configured your DNS records for email. Here's a breakdown and solution:
The Issue:

You're using a shared hosting service (iFastNet) with email functionality.
Initially, you had a working setup with MX records pointing to the shared domain (sv63.ifastnet12.org). This allowed email sending and receiving.
However, switching the MX record to an A record pointing to the same IP (sv63.ifastnet12.org) broke receiving external emails.

Why it Breaks:

MX records tell external servers where to deliver emails for your domain (ender.ing).

An A record points a domain name to an IP address. While they both point to the same IP, they serve different purposes.

When you use an A record for MX, email servers might get confused because the SSL certificate on the shared IP likely only validates "sv63.ifastnet12.org," not your domain. This raises security concerns for email servers, potentially leading to them rejecting emails addressed to your domain (ender.ing).


The Solution:
There are two options, depending on your hosting plan and desired flexibility:

Stick with MX record pointing to shared domain (sv63.ifastnet12.org):

This is the simpler option if your plan includes email hosting.
Leave the MX record pointing to sv63.ifastnet12.org. This ensures proper email delivery and receiving for your domain.


Use a dedicated email provider with custom MX records:

This option offers more control and potentially better security, but might require additional fees.
Choose a separate email hosting provider offering custom MX records. They'll provide specific MX record values and you need to configure in your DNS settings.
Update your DNS records to point the MX records to the values provided by your chosen email provider.



Additional Tips:

Check your iFastNet documentation: See if they offer dedicated email hosting with custom MX records.
Consider email provider options: Research email hosting providers with good reputations and features that suit your needs.
Propagate DNS changes: Allow 24-72 hours for DNS changes to reflect globally after updating your records.

By implementing one of these solutions, you should be able to receive external emails to your domain (ender.ing) while still using the shared hosting service for your website.

"When you use an A record for MX" - this is a completely nonsensical statement. Leaving aside that a DNS RR cannot be BOTH A and MX type, the MX must resolve to a A (or an AAAA) for anything to connect to it.

I misused "A record for MX" because an MX record relies on an A record, not the other way around. My aim was to explain the problem caused by using only an A record (pointing to the server IP) for email, when an MX record pointing to the mail server is needed.
